# Showing that the Yoneda Map is Natural

Tags: category-theory

From *Categories for the Working Mathematician* pg. 61:

[image]

[image]

I understand everything about the Yoneda Lemma except this naturalness component. In particular, I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around the functors $N$ and $E$.

**Questions.**

1. What is $D(f,-)$? I understand what $D(o,-)$ for $o$ an object of $D$. But now $o$ is a morphism.
2. How is $Nat(D(f,-), F)$ an arrow from $Nat(D(r,-), K)$ to $Nat(D(r',-),K')$?
3. What is the morphism function of $E$? That is, what does $E(F:K \rightarrow K', f:r \rightarrow r')$ map to?

Comment: For what it's worth, I find the [wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma) of Yoneda to be far more lucid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Nat}{\operatorname{Nat}}$

1. If $f\colon r\rightarrow r'$ is an arrow, then $D(f,-)\colon D(r',-) \rightarrow D(r,-)$ is the natural transformation given by precomposing $f$, i. e.
   $$
   D(f,s)\colon D(r',s)\longrightarrow D(r,s),\quad g\longmapsto g\circ f\quad \text{ (for all objects $s$ in $D$).}
   $$
2. Given an arrow $f\colon r\rightarrow r'$ and a natural map $F\colon K\rightarrow K'$, then $\Nat(D(f,-),F)\colon \Nat(D(r,-),K) \rightarrow \Nat(D(r',-),K')$ is simply given by
   $$
   \alpha\longmapsto F\circ \alpha\circ D(f,-)
   $$
   for any $\alpha\in \Nat(D(r,-),K)$, noticing that both $F$ and $D(f,-)$ are natural maps as is the composite of such.
3. If again $f\colon r\rightarrow r'$ is an arrow and $F\colon K\rightarrow K'$ is a natural map, then $E(\langle F,f\rangle)\colon Kr\rightarrow K'r'$ is given by the composite
   $$
   Kr\xrightarrow{F_r} K'r \xrightarrow{K'(f)} K'r'.
   $$ 
   Notice that this is the same as defining $E(\langle F,f\rangle)$ by
   $$
   Kr \xrightarrow{K(f)} Kr' \xrightarrow {F_{r'}} K'r'
   $$
   since $F$ is natural.

Comment: Just to be clear, in (2): $\text{Nat}(D(f,-),F) = N(F,f)$, correct? (Here I'm using the notation $N$ as in the passage from Mac Lane above).

Comment: Yes, this is correct.